# How to tell if output was sent to stderr

Tags: bash, stderr

I have to wrap a command in a bash script.

If the command exits with an exit code != 0 and/or writes to stderr a failure occurred which has to be handled.

The first condition is simple.
But how to tell if there was output to stderr? I don't want to intercept or capture the output (unless there is no other way), I simply need to know *if* there was any.

Comment: I don't think there's any way unless the command itself notifies in some way. Capturing stderr and checking if there's any is easy and I am not really sure why you want to do this as typically, one would *capture* either or both. Not just checking if there's something in the error. Moreover, a command might print warning messages to stderr too. So the reliable way to check for *failure* is by using the return code.

Comment: If there was a sensible return code in any case you were right; unfortunately it is not. But the combination of stderr and return code gives us the correct result.

Comment: The exit code can be retrieved from `$?`. With regards to `stderr`, I am not sure if it can be checked or probably you need to write to a temp file

Comment: Do you care about stdout ?

Comment: Yes, I care for stdout; neither stdout nor stderr shall be changed

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/453598/determine-if-output-is-stdout-or-stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by noting that a process's **file descriptors are exposed in /proc/**. For example if you do

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/2
lrwx------ 1 meuh meuh 64 Jul 16 10:06 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/2
```

in an xterm or similar you can see that stderr for **self**, bash, is a
pty. Follow the symlink in the `ls` to get the real time of last modification of the pty:

```
$ ls -lL /proc/self/fd/2
crw--w---- 1 meuh tty 136, 2 Jul 16 10:05 /proc/self/fd/2
```

A better command to use is **stat** which gives better time resolution.

```
$ stat -L -c %y /proc/self/fd/2
2015-07-16 10:03:54.553125813
```

So simply save the timestamp before your command, and compare it after the
command to see if it is different.

```
before=$(stat -L -c %y /proc/self/fd/2)
if mycommand &&
 after=$(stat -L -c %y /proc/self/fd/2) &&
 [ "$after" = "$before" ]
then echo 'command ok'
else echo 'command fail'
fi
```

Comment: That would only work on Linux.  On OS X, for example, there is no `/proc`, on UNIX's that do support `/proc` the layout differs.  `stat(1)` is also GNU specific.

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you very much. It is not portable, but that is not important for my specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: "tee" stderr to a temporary file and check if this file has non-zero size at command end.